# How to dynamically set HTML <input> names with Thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

I have a form that receives a 2D array from the controller and I have generated the table through thymeleaf.

```html
<div class="col-4 offset-4">
  <form id="sudokuBoard" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" class="form-group text-center">
    <div class="container">
      <table class="row-eq-height table-striped table-bordered text-center">
        <!--/*@thymesVar id="board" type=""*/-->
        <tr th:each="row: ${board}">
          <td th:each="value: ${row}">
            <div th:switch="${value}" class="col-xs-4">
              <input name="cellValue" th:case="0" class="content form-control input" style="text-align:center" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" maxlength="1" value="0" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" oninput="moveMade()">
              <input name="cellValue" th:case="*" class="content form-control input" style="text-align:center;background-color:lightgreen" type="text" th:value="${value}" readonly>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <div class="gap-10"></div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Check Solution</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="btnNewGame">New Game</button>
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="solveBoard"> Solve Puzzle</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

All input fields have the same name and I want to dynamically assign the names through Thymeleaf so they become `cellValueX` in order to differentiate each cell in order to check the validity of moves entered by the user.

Answer (score 1):

You use the attribute `th:name`. [See this for a list of attributes you can use with Thymeleaf](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes).  I don't know specifically from your code what you want to use for `X` in `cellValueX`, but possibly something like this?

```
<tr th:each="row, y: ${board}">
    <td th:each="value, x: ${row}">
        <input th:name="|cellValue${x.index}_${y.index}|" ... />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for. I was playing around with `th:name` but couldn't figure it out.